# Pass parameters to Powershell using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters

I have a  C# function which actually invokes a powershell asynchronously
Below is my code:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(scriptFile,false);
                PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("var", "Value");
                PSDataCollection <PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();

                IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

                while (result.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
                    }
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for pipeline to finish...");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

            }
```

while this works like i nee to to , the addition of the parameter doesn't seem to do any thing. I have made that parameter compulsory in powershell , no success nothing happens then. If its not compulsory it just works and doesn't process the parameter.

My Powershell is:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
[string]$var
)
. "C:\Data\initiate.PS1"
write-output "Value is $var"
```

The output is:

In Initiation  -- This is coming from the PS initation script

Value is

Waiting for pipeline to finish...

IF I make the parameter Required as true in Powershell the output is:

Waiting for pipeline to finish...

I have tried changing he scope in the PowerShellInstance.AddScript, no use.
This might look like a duplicate question but I couldn't find the solution hence asking here.
The msdn link i used to create this code is at: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `AddScript` -> `AddCommand`

Comment: This worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add/mark PetSerAl's comment as answer, worked for me. Thank you

```
AddScript -> AddCommand
```